# Supposed 'brain training'

Tags: neuroscience, working-memory, brain-training, brain-development, placebo

The term brain training is nothing new, however how effective is the 'N-back' method, does this work scientifically speaking?

There are mixed reviews on this: 
one claiming it works
https://www.highiqpro.com/dual-n-back/latest-n-back-training-studies

Another it doesn't
https://www.cambridgebrainsciences.com/more/articles/brain-training-still-not-vital

Comment: Hint: is either of these trying to sell you something?

Comment: See also the [general question on whether brain training is effective](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/is-brain-training-effective)

Comment: @BryanKrause  Hi, no not in particular, Im referring to the N back test developed by William Kirchner

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Thanks for the link, the answer was explored in-depth. Much appreciated. My understanding is that N-back may increase fluid intelligence and relational frame may increase general IQ, correct?